# About a client for pusher written in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I want to write a module which need to be able to push message to pusher in Erlang. I found this repo https://github.com/bradfordw/pusherl, which is not maintained anymore, but I think I can adapt to make it work. I followed the README, and I ran successfully all the Rebar command. Then I open the rebar console by the command

```
./rel/pusherl/bin/pusherl console
```

So the server should start. But then when I try to call

```
gen_server:call(pusherl_server, {push, {"ChannelName", "EventName", "Payload"}}).
```

Then it throws error:

```
exception exit: {noproc,{gen_server,call,
                                   [pusherl_server,
                                    {push, 

    {"ChannelName","EventName","Payload"}}]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 182)
```

I'm quite new with Erlang and OTP, and it takes me half of the day to make it work but not successful. Please help me to solve this. I really appreciate.

By the way, if you know any other pusher client, please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Here is the code to for gen_server callback:

```
-module(pusherl_server).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).
-define(JP, fun(K,V) -> string:join([K,V],"=") end).

-record(state,{app_id, key, secret}).

-export([start_link/0]).

-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

start_link() ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init(_) ->
  {ok, PusherAppId} = application:get_env(pusher_app_id),
  {ok, PusherKey} = application:get_env(pusher_key),
  {ok, PusherSecret} = application:get_env(pusher_secret),
  {ok, #state{app_id=PusherAppId, key=PusherKey, secret=PusherSecret}}.

handle_call({push, {ChannelName, EventName, Payload}}, _From, State) ->
  case http_request(ChannelName, EventName, Payload, State) of
    {ok, _} -> {reply, ok, State};
    {error, _} -> {reply, error, State}
  end;
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
  {noreply, ok, State}.

handle_cast({push, {ChannelName, EventName, Payload}}, State) ->
  case http_request(ChannelName, EventName, Payload, State) of
    {ok, _} -> {noreply, ok, State};
    {error, _} -> {noreply, error, State}
  end;
handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
  {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
  {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
  ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
  {ok, State}.

http_request(ChannelName, EventName, Payload, Config) when is_list(ChannelName), is_record(Config, state) ->
  {ok, ReqProps} = http_request_props(Payload, EventName, ChannelName, Config),
    httpc:request(post, ReqProps, [], []).

http_request_props(Payload, EventName, ChannelName, #state{app_id=AppId, key=AppKey, secret=AppSecret}) ->
    Md5String = lists:flatten([io_lib:format("~2.16.0b",[N]) || <<N>> <= crypto:md5(Payload)]),
  ToSign = ["POST",
                lists:flatten(["/apps/", AppId, "/channels/", ChannelName, "/events"]),
                string:join([?JP("auth_key", AppKey),
        ?JP("auth_timestamp", get_time_as_string()),
        ?JP("auth_version", "1.0"),
        ?JP("body_md5", Md5String),
                ?JP("name", EventName)
                ],"&")
  ],
    AuthSignature = signed_params(ToSign, AppSecret),
    QueryParams = [
        ?JP("auth_key", AppKey),
      ?JP("auth_timestamp", get_time_as_string()),
      ?JP("auth_version","1.0"),
      ?JP("body_md5", Md5String),
        ?JP("auth_signature", AuthSignature),
        ?JP("name", EventName)
    ],
  Url = http_api_url(AppId, ChannelName, QueryParams),
  {ok, {Url, [], "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", Payload}}.

http_api_url(AppId, ChannelName, QueryParams) ->
  QueryString = string:join(QueryParams,"&"),
  lists:flatten(["http://api.pusherapp.com/apps/",AppId,"/channels/",ChannelName,"/events?", QueryString]).

get_time_as_string() ->
  {M, S, _} = now(),
  integer_to_list(((M * 1000000) + S)).

signed_params(Params, Secret) ->
    lists:flatten([io_lib:format("~2.16.0b",[N]) || <<N:8>> <= sha2:hmac_sha256(Secret, string:join(Params,"\n"))]).
```

Comment: I still met the problem that I mentioned. Please anyone help me to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`noproc` means that the process you're trying to call is not running.  You need to start it with:

```
pusherl_server:start_link().
```

Note that this will link the `pusherl_server` process to the calling process.  If you're running this in the shell, and then do something that causes an error, the error will propagate across the link to the `pusherl_server` process and kill it, so then you have to start it again.

To avoid that, you can either unlink the process after starting it:

```
{ok, Pid} = pusherl_server:start_link().
unlink(Pid).
```

or add a `start` function to the module, that does the same as `start_link` except it calls `gen_server:start` instead of `gen_server:start_link`.

Comment: Another option is to execute `catch_exception(true).` in the shell to tell it to catch exceptions instead of letting them kill itself.

Comment: Also, once he gets past the `noproc` problem, he's going to run into the problem that `pusherl_server:init` requires a few application environment variables to be set.

Comment: Actually, I run it by the command of rebar ``./rel/pusherl/bin/pusherl console``. So I think the server has started already. Let my try with the erl console.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I edited my question to make it clearer. Thanks